# A presentation of the infinite dihedral group.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

This is from Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, 2nd edition:

[image: Part 1]
[image: Part 2]

Some pages below he gives an example:

[image: Part 3]

In saying that $G=\langle x,y\mid x^2=1,y^2=1\rangle$, he is using the definition of presentation given in (2) in the picture. But a presentation, according to the author, is an epimorphism $\pi$ from some free group $F$ to $G$. In this example I want to find $\pi$. So, first I have to find the $Y$ and $S$ in definition (1), where $X=Y^{\pi}$ and then $F$ will be the free group on $Y$. Humm... $F$ I can already find it. It will simply be the free group on a set with two elements. But how do I find $Y$?

Comment: Good question! I'm not sure. Are the isomorphism theorems covered in the book so far?

Comment: Yes, they are in the preceding chapter, chapter one, which is a summary of material normally presented in a whole book on group theory.

Comment: $Y = \{x,y\}$ and $S = \{x^2,y^2\}$. Maybe you are confused because it is common practice to regard $x$ and $y$ as elements of $G$, but that is actually abuse of notation. $x$ and $y$ are elements of $F$, and it is their images $\pi(x)$ and $\pi(y)$ that are elements of $G$.

Comment: Well then $\pi$ could be the natural homomorphism form $F$ to $Y^F$ (normal closure of $Y$ in $F$). The problem is now to find $Y^F$. But I can't even find $<Y>$!

Comment: You seem to be confused about the notation. $Y = \langle x,y \rangle = F$ , $G = F/\langle S^F \rangle$, and $\pi:F \to G$ is the natural homomorphism. $\langle S^F \rangle$ consists (by definition) of all product $t_1^{g_1}t_2^{g_2} \cdots t_r^{g_r}$, where $r$ can be any non-negative integer, each $t_i$ is $x^2$ or $y^2$,  and each $g_i \in G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The free group $F=F(Y)$ on a set $Y$ has the defining property that given a function of sets $f\colon Y \to G$, where $G$ is (the underlying set of) a group, there is a homomorphism $\hat f\colon F \to G$ that *extends* $f$ in the sense that if $\iota\colon Y \to F$ is the natural inclusion (of sets), then $\hat f\iota = f$. Therefore to define the map $\pi$, it suffices to choose the image of the elements of $Y$ in $G$.

So let $Y = \{a,b\}$ be a two-element set and $G$ the infinite dihedral group as defined by the presentation $\langle x,y \mid x^2 = 1, y^2 = 1\rangle$. I will choose the function $Y \to G$ sending $a$ to $x$ and $b$ to $y$. The resulting homomorphism $\pi \colon F\to G$ is surjective because $\{x,y\}$ is a set of generators for $G$.

Comment: Thanks. So I know the restriction of $\pi$ to $Y$ and that's all. I don't really know what $\pi$ is in this example (infinite dihedral group).

Comment: @stf91: Yes you do: every element of $F$ is a product of $a$s, $b$s, and their inverses. And a given such word is mapped to the corresponding word in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah! [EMPTY SPACE]

Comment: According to Rylee Lyman (see answer) $\pi$ is the presentation $<x,y| x^2=1, y^2=1>$. But then Ker $\pi$ is the normal closure of $\{a^2, b^2\}. I can't see how I can prove this. Let $K= Ker \pi, S=\{a^2, b^2\}$ and $S^F$ the normal closure of $S$. To begin with, what is $S^F$?

Comment: According to Rylee Lyman (see answer) $\pi$ is the presentation $<x,y| x^2=1, y^2=1>$. But then Ker $\pi$ is the normal closure of $\{a^2, b^2\}$. I can't see how I can prove this. Let $K=$  Ker $\pi, S=\{a^2, b^2\}$ and $S^F$ the normal closure of $S$. To begin with, what is $S^F$?

Comment: The notation $S^F$ is meant to remind you of the sometimes used exponential notation for conjugation, namely $h^g = g^{-1}hg$. Indeed, it might be a useful exercise to prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ generated by a set of elements $S$, then the *normal closure* of $H$ in $G$ is the group generated by the set $S^F = \{ s^g \mid s \in S,\ g\in G\}$.

Comment: Modulo the exercise, proving that $\mathrm{Ker}\pi$ is the normal closure of $H = \langle a^2,b^2\rangle$ should be enlightening. Showing that the normal closure of $H$ is contained in $\mathrm{Ker}\pi$ shouldn't be too hard. Showing the opposite containment is either true by definition or more difficult, depending on your perspective.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I should have written $S^G$, not $S^F$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103158/discussion-between-stf91-and-rylee-lyman).